# Grunt module to inject HTML templates

Tags: html, templates, gruntjs

Recently started using Grunt as a build tool for a web app I'm hobbyist developing. I have a series of HTML files (to be used as templates), in a single folder, that I'd like injected at a particular point in the  main HTML file.

Ideally, I could also wrap each file in a  tag, but having to manually include this in the template files themselves is acceptable.

Is there an existing Grunt module to perform this?

EDIT: I may have worded my problem poorly before. Essentially, I have a single HTML file where the app will run (Single page app, business simulation game). In a separate folder, I have a series of HTML templates. Each of these template represents a dialog, or custom info page, something of that nature. As the app is developed, more and more templates will be in this folder.

Rather than manually including each one in my page, I'd like a way to automate injecting them that I can manage through Grunt.

Comment: Not sure how this is related to grunt. Looks like what you need to include them as ejs files!

Comment: @Kiran reworded my question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 14):

I may be late to answer this question, but for anyone that end up here, I found this grunt-plugins, maybe they help you too:

- [grunt-replace](https://github.com/outaTiME/grunt-replace).
- [grunt-html-build](https://github.com/spatools/grunt-html-build).
- [grunt-processhtml](https://github.com/dciccale/grunt-processhtml).

Comment: processhtml's ability to add custom blocks is really handy when it comes to template injection.

Comment: grunt-bake looks like a good option too.
https://github.com/roboshoes/grunt-bake