# Grunt inject CSS file into <style> tag

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I am looking for a solution for injecting a CSS file into a **style** tag with Grunt.

Example :

**Style.css**

```
.foo { background:red; }
```

**index-before.html ( Before Grunt task )**

```
<html>
<head>

  <style type="text/css">

//output Style.css here

  </style>

</head>
<body>
....
</body>
</html>
```

**index-after.html ( After Grunt task )**

```
<html>
<head>

  <style type="text/css">

.foo { background:red; }

  </style>

</head>
<body>
....
</body>
</html>
```

---

**Solution with grunt-replace (Thank Andy)**

```
replace: {
    dist: {
        options: {
            patterns: [
                {
                    match: 'include_css_style_tag',
                    replacement: '<%= grunt.file.read("assets/css/styles.css") %>'
                }
            ]
        },
        files: [
            {expand: true, flatten: true, src: ['index.html'], dest: 'build/'}
        ]
    }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<style type="text/css">
@@include_css_style_tag
</style>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grunt module to inject HTML templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270602/grunt-module-to-inject-html-templates)

Comment: i think  not only duplicate, but also too broad and possible asking for a library.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to get this to work without duplicating the HTML file in a build folder? Ideally just replace what is inside the style tag via an unique ID. That way you only have one file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`replace`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-replace).

In your HTML use a indicator that is recognised by `replace`:

```
<style type="text/css">
  @@mycss
</style>
```

[Load your css file](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file) into a variable within your Gruntfile.js:

```
var css = grunt.file.read(cssfilepath [, options]);
```

Then add a replace task, something like:

```
replace: {
  dist: {
    options: {
      patterns: [{
        match: 'mycss',
        replacement: css
      }]
    },
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      flatten: true,
      src: ['src/index.html'],
      dest: 'src/index.html'
    }]
  }
};
```

Note, I've not tested this, but if you follow the `replace` documentation you should figure it out for your system.